# How to filter master workbook to send result as a table, not a file?

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

My mission is to filter a master workbook to send results to their respective recipients. The recipients and body of the email which will be located in a workbook.

I have to send over 50 emails, with results in table format, to over 50 different recipients.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub split()

    Dim wswb As String
    Dim wssh As String

    Dim vColumn As Variant

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim vcounter As Variant
    Dim vfilter As String

    wswb = ActiveWorkbook.Name
    wssh = ActiveSheet.Name

    vColumn = InputBox("Select Column to Filter", "Column Selection")

    Columns(vColumn).Copy
    Sheets.Add

    ActiveSheet.Name = "Working_Magic"
    Range("A1").PasteSpecial

    Columns("A").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlYes

    vcounter = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 2 To vcounter
        vfilter = Sheets("Working_Magic").Cells(i, 1)
        Sheets(wssh).Activate
        ActiveSheet.Columns.AutoFilter field:=Columns(vColumn).Column, Criteria1:=vfilter
        Cells.Copy
        Workbooks.Add
      
        Range("A1").PasteSpecial
        If vfilter <> "" Then
            ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs ThisWorkbook.Path & "\DSAttachments_to_email\" & vfilter
        Else
            ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs ThisWorkbook.Path & "\DSAttachments_to_email\_Empty"
        End If
        ActiveWorkbook.Close
        Workbooks(wswb).Activate
    
    Next i
    Sheets("Working_Magic").Delete
    
End Sub
```

I do not need to save the attachment in a folder as shown in the code above rather send report to all respective recipients.

Comment: split this in two routines. Maybe one to collect the data in a array and the other to run over the array and send the mails. Then you know that the data is correct and it will be much more easy to debug then to do it all in once.

Comment: @ThomasLudewig, sorry just a bit new on VBA. Could you kindly show us, please? This will be a point of reference for most. Also, I'm not aware of how to paste excel attachments in emails as copy and paste in the table format. (as opposed to sending a whole attachment workbook) Really appreciate you looking into this, Thanks

Comment: Sure i could do that. Means that i than make other peoples job for free. I also have no own need for a spam mailer. All you need can be found via google by small own afford. LOOK for VBA and VB6.And BTW: this approach of a solution is in my eyes also a no go.

Comment: @ThomasLudewig had a search and couldn't find it. Would it be possible to answer on here, please?  I appreciate your help. Thanks in advance

Comment: After the weekend, at this moment i am to full with my work load.

Comment: Hi @ThomasLudewig, any luck trying out this issue?

Comment: On a side note, you should not create a Sub that has same name as builtin functions. `Split(...)` is one of the builtin functions frequently used.

Comment: Can you explain a little more about what your data looks like? What filter do you need to apply and where is the recipient located? From your example I'm assuming you filter by recipient, and copy all the lines with that recipient on into the email. Is that correct?

Comment: Hi @Plutian, The aim is to have a Master File(EXCEL SHEET) which will contain email addresses to over 50 companies with cc'd email addresses, subject and body massage. The task will be to filter a column and send to the respective companies with a copy and paste attachment as opposed to an excel attachment. Then send to a company. Thanks in advance (It would also be nice to have a tracker to output to the user as "attachment send to comp21", etc but not necessary).

Comment: Did Alex L's answer work for you? If not, is there more you're looking for?

Comment: @seadoggie01, pardon me as I'm fairly new and stilll learning. I have been running Alex's code and keep bumping into errors. I have fixed a few but now stuck on Set table_range = Sheets(sheet_name_range).Range(range_string)   throwing me this error: Runtime error '9': Subscript out of range. It will be supa if you can help me. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would approach it one of two ways, convert the range to an HTML table and insert that into the email or use `SendKeys '^c', true` and then `SendKeys '^v', true`. My preference is the first option and here is the code:

```
Sub LoopThroughTable()

    Set ws = ActiveSheet

    For i = 2 To Sheet1.Cells(Sheet1.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        email_to = Sheet1.Cells(i, 5).Value
        email_subject = Sheet1.Cells(i, 4).Value

        folder_path = Sheet1.Cells(i, 2).Value

        Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        'Set fld = FSO.GetFolder(folder_path)
        If FSO.FolderExists(folder_path) Then
            'Nothing, folder is good
        Else
            'Just save to desktop
            folder_path = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SpecialFolders("Desktop")
            Sheet1.Cells(i, 2).Value = folder_path
        End If

        If Right(folder_path, 1) <> "\" Then
            Sheet1.Cells(i, 2).Value = folder_path & "\"
        End If

        file_path = Sheet1.Cells(i, 2).Value & Sheet1.Cells(i, 3).Value

        sheet_name = Sheet1.Cells(i, 1).Value
        sheet_name_range = Sheet1.Cells(i, 9).Value
        Dim table_range As Range
        Dim range_string As String
        range_string = Sheet1.Cells(i, 10)
        Set table_range = Sheets(sheet_name_range).Range(range_string) 'Range("A3:C8") 'etc.

        email_body = Sheet1.Cells(i, 8).Value & "<br><br>" & ConvertRangeToHTMLTable(table_range)

        CopySheetAndSave sheet_name, file_path

        SendOutlookMessage email_to, email_subject, file_path, email_body
        ThisWorkbook.Activate
    Next i

    ws.Activate

End Sub

Sub CopySheetAndSave(ByVal sheet_name As String, ByVal full_path As String)

    SheetName = sheet_name
    FullPath = full_path

    Sheets(SheetName).Select
    Sheets(SheetName).Copy
    'ChDir "C:\Users\username\Downloads"
    Workbooks(Workbooks.Count).SaveAs Filename:=FullPath, FileFormat:= _
        xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
    Workbooks(Workbooks.Count).Close
End Sub


Sub SendOutlookMessage(ByVal email_to As String, ByVal email_subject As String, ByVal file_path As String, ByVal email_body As String)

    emailTo = email_to
    emailSub = email_subject
    FullPath = file_path
    HTMLBODY = email_body

    DoEvents
    Application.Wait 1

    Dim olApp As Object
    Dim olMail As Object

    Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set olMail = olApp.CreateItem(0)
    With olMail
        .to = emailTo
        .Subject = emailSub
        .Attachments.Add (FullPath)

        .HTMLBODY = HTMLBODY
        DoEvents

        .Display
        Application.Wait 1
        .Send

    End With

    Application.Wait 1

    Set olMail = Nothing
    Set olApp = Nothing

End Sub

'Following function converts Excel range to HTML table
'Taken from https://excelsirji.com/vba-code-to-convert-excel-range-into-html-table/
Public Function ConvertRangeToHTMLTable(rInput As Range) As String
    'Declare variables
    Dim rRow As Range
    Dim rCell As Range
    Dim strReturn As String
    'Define table format and font
    strReturn = "<Table border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='7' style='border-collapse:collapse;border:none'>  "
    'Loop through each row in the range
    For Each rRow In rInput.Rows
        'Start new html row
        strReturn = strReturn & " <tr align='Center'; style='height:10.00pt'> "
        For Each rCell In rRow.Cells
            'If it is row 1 then it is header row that need to be bold
            If rCell.Row = 1 Then
                strReturn = strReturn & "<td valign='Center' style='border:solid windowtext 1.0pt; padding:0cm 5.4pt 0cm 5.4pt;height:1.05pt'><b>" & rCell.Text & "</b></td>"
            Else
                strReturn = strReturn & "<td valign='Center' style='border:solid windowtext 1.0pt; padding:0cm 5.4pt 0cm 5.4pt;height:1.05pt'>" & rCell.Text & "</td>"
            End If
        Next rCell
        'End a row
        strReturn = strReturn & "</tr>"
    Next rRow
    'Close the font tag
    strReturn = strReturn & "</font></table>"
    'Return html format
    ConvertRangeToHTMLTable = strReturn
End Function
```

Note that the ConvertRangeToHTMLTable is not my function I took it from:
https://excelsirji.com/vba-code-to-convert-excel-range-into-html-table/

I have a helper/loader function LoopThroughTable as a way to send as many emails as in the table on Sheet1 like this:

[image: Excel Screenshot]

Note that I also send a specific sheet only as an attachment but you can modify that code to remove that part if you don't wish to do that. Any questions please ask in the comments and if this solves your problem please consider to mark it as the correct answer.

Excel Sheet attached here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1yO0HvonMV6HHyLRjmHS2PHVquIDvjI5S/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range. How do i solve this please ?

Comment: @MartinQ: Excel Workbook here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1yO0HvonMV6HHyLRjmHS2PHVquIDvjI5S/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Hey @MartinQ, I assume you have an error like you said here `Set table_range = Sheets(sheet_name_range).Range(range_string) throwing me this error: Runtime error '9': Subscript out of range`, due to not having valid sheet name and/or range name in cells(2,1) and Cells(2,9). This code is the point when these values are used: `sheet_name = Sheet1.Cells(i, 1).Value & sheet_name_range = Sheet1.Cells(i, 9).Value`, You need to have the data set out as I had in the screenshot - If I attach my Excel Workbook here does that help?